# Resolve a problem ComboBox and a TextCtrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I want to make that when selecting an element in the ComboBox print a message that is in the tuple in the TextCtrl, depending on the item I chose

When I did it the way I investigated, I throw an error.

```
import wx

#Mods
Nom_Mods = ["Alca v3", "Barcelone v1", "Anti-Fed (French)", "Elegance v3"]
Info_Mods = ["(ZL + Joystick2) To Open Menu\n(B) To close Menu\nCreate by KillerGamer81"]
#EndMods


class PageOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    #Controls
    self.Listade_Menus = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, pos=(10,80), size=(173,22), choices = Nom_Mods, style= wx.CB_READONLY)
    Cuadro_de_info = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", pos=(200,80), size=(175,80), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        no_sys_menu = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.RESIZE_BORDER) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="ProyectoU", style=no_sys_menu, size=(400,225))
        ico = wx.Icon('Recursos/icono.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(ico)

        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        page1 = PageOne(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Inyec/Conec")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: what error ? we can't see your screen, we can't read in your mind. And don't expect taht we will run code to see this error (besides it can work correctly on our computers). Always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error, would be a indentation error!
The problem is that you are not `Binding` to the `ComboBox` event i.e. when you make a selection an event will fire, which must be caught and acted upon.
You need to catch that event and put the currently selected text from the combobox (or whatever) into the textctrl. Currently you are making no attempt to do that.

Here is what I assume you want.

```
import wx

#Mods
Nom_Mods = ["Alca v3", "Barcelone v1", "Anti-Fed (French)", "Elegance v3"]
Info_Mods = ["(ZL + Joystick2) To Open Menu\n(B) To close Menu\nCreate by KillerGamer81"]
#EndMods


class PageOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    #Controls
        self.Listade_Menus = wx.ComboBox(self, -1, pos=(10,80), size=(173,22), choices = Nom_Mods, style= wx.CB_READONLY)

        #Bind a callback to the event emitted by the Combobox selection
        self.Listade_Menus.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.Nom_Mods_Selected)

        self.Cuadro_de_info = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", pos=(200,80), size=(175,80), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY)

        # When a selection is made populate the textctrl with the selected text
    def Nom_Mods_Selected(self, event):
        self.Cuadro_de_info.SetValue(self.Listade_Menus.GetStringSelection())


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        no_sys_menu = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & (~wx.RESIZE_BORDER) & (~wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="ProyectoU", style=no_sys_menu, size=(400,225))
        ico = wx.Icon('Recursos/icono.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(ico)

        # Here we create a panel and a notebook on the panel
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        # create the page windows as children of the notebook
        page1 = PageOne(nb)

        # add the pages to the notebook with the label to show on the tab
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Inyec/Conec")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I had the indentation error because when I wrote the post I wrote the code wrong. Actually wanted to print the message that is in the tuple (Info_Mods). But thanks to you I already understood how I could do it.